# Impossible to connect to SSO idp

Tags: symfony, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have a question. we have an app under symfony 5.4 which provide SAML connector via the OneloginSamlBundle bundle.
This app is installed is different customers.
Normally in majority of customers, when we connect to their idp, we have an answer like this :

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
...
  <saml:Subject>
  ...
    <saml:AttributeStatement>
      <saml:Attribute Name="uid">
        <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">john_doe</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
```

and we are able to map the attribute uid with the username in our application

The problem is we have with a customer which use AD FS is the response is like this :

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ... >   
  <Subject>
           <NameID>john_doe</NameID>
            ...
        </Subject>
```

And as in the bundle we have this code to retrive the attibute, it doesn't work

`$entries = $this->_queryAssertion('/saml:AttributeStatement/saml:Attribute');`

Do you know if AD FS could be configured to send a response with `<saml:Attribute>` ?

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution :

customer added a claim rule (https://help.blackboard.com/Learn/Administrator/SaaS/Authentication/Implement_Authentication/SAML_Authentication_Provider_Type/SAML_Setup_Guide_for_ADFS) with the good Attribute Name and even the xml message is without the `saml:` prefix, it worked